# How to require once all my php files?

Tags: php

I Get tired of require over and over again in each of my php files, is the a way that gets automatically require all needed php file in all folders once.

i have used this but only works for one folder

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'logic/'. $class .'.php';
});
```

please help i trying to improve my OOPS php by reducing require.

Comment: You could possibly create a "master require file", which includes the file you need, then just require that on all pages. Or use `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini.

Comment: If you work with classes, you can use http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: how does auto_prepend_file work.

Comment: im working with folders and subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use in this way in which you can define multiple paths for file to search for.

```
spl_autoload_register(array("Loader","classLoader"));
class Loader
{
    public static function classLoader($className)
    {
        if(!empty($className))
        {
            foreach(array(
                "path/to/path1/",
                "path/to/path2/",
                "path/to/path3/"
            ) as $path)
            {
                $classPath=$path.$className.".php";
                if(file_exists($classPath))
                {
                    require_once $classPath;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay it great but i want to require all php file without calling

Comment: @NkhangweniMulelu for that you do one thing you might have the list of all files you want to include. just mention all those files in the array of above mentioned code. and remove that line in which i am appending .php